# How do we get feedback from the users of UXSE about how they use UXSE?

Tags: discussion

I have some students interested in doing some research to find out how people use UXSE (since I am encouraging them to take advantage of it), and was wondering if posting the link to the survey on chat is a good way to get this type of information, or if there is some data available by doing clever queries on data.uxstackechange?